# Why does this.fill = "black" typed in console not change the colour of the circle?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am creating circles for fun. I am generating them from a function. I want to be able to change their parameters in the console once they are created. Why can't I do this? My question is specific to this method - why am I not able to change them this way?

`a.fill = "black";` written in the console does not change the parameter of the circle object

```js
const container = document.body
let svgContainer = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svgContainer.style.width = "100vw"
svgContainer.style.height = "100vw"
svgContainer.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 500 750");
container.appendChild(svgContainer);

function makeCircle(cx, cy, r, fill, stroke, id) {
  this.cx = cx;
  this.cy = cy;
  this.r = r;
  this.fill = fill;
  this.stroke = stroke;
  this.id = id;
  let newCircle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  newCircle.setAttribute("cx", cx);
  newCircle.setAttribute("cy", cy);
  newCircle.setAttribute("r", r);
  newCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', fill);
  newCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', stroke);
  svgContainer.appendChild(newCircle);
}

let a = new makeCircle(50, 300, 20, '#493fea', 'green');
```

Comment: `this` inside the function is not the same as `this` in the console. Also, it's just a property, you've to set the attribute value of the element to change the color.

Comment: The question is confusing. The title says “`this.fill = "black"`” while the question body says “`a.fill = "black"`”. Are you having issues with both?

Comment: `newCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', fill);` doesn't create a reference. Changing `fill` *after* that line has run isn't going to change the attribute value.

Comment: 1. You can delete the first 6 lines of code of your function. 2. At the end of the function return the shape `return newCircle`.3. Now you can set the fill `a.setAttribute('fill', 'gold');`

Comment: newCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', fill); doesn't create a reference. - can you expand on the reference part? Why not?

Comment: The question is confusing. The title says “this.fill = "black"” while the question body says “a.fill = "black"”. Are you having issues with both? - you're right. I meant a.fill = 'black' in the console does not change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to change their parameters in the console once they are created. Why can't I do this?

because you create a new object with a property `cx` for example and seperately from that, a `<circle cx="..." />` and the property in your created object and the attribute on the `<circle />` have no connection to each other after they were once initially set. You'd have to make such a connection so that when you change the property the attribute is updated.

Here an example that does that. It's a somewhat generic function that takes the name of an element and a list of its specific SVG attributes and then returns a function like your `makeCircle`. But with the mentioned properties on the object.

Since it's generic it doesn't take attributes like `makeCircle(cx, cy, r, fill, stroke, id)` but instead a single object with the attributes you want to set: `makeCircle({ cx, cy, r, fill, stroke, id })`.

```js
// a few tools:

// to turn `stroke-width` into `strokeWidth`
const camelCase = str => str.toLowerCase().replace(/-[a-z]/gi, v => v[1].toUpperCase());

// takes a list of attribute names and creates a bunch of property definitions that get/set that value from the attribute
// see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties
const attrs2props = (attrs) => Object.fromEntries(attrs.map(attr => [camelCase(attr), {
  configurable: true,
  get() {
    return this.getAttributeNS(null, attr)
  },
  set(value) {
    this.setAttributeNS(null, attr, value)
  }
}]));

const sharedSVGAttributes = attrs2props(["clip-path", "clip-rule", "color", "color-interpolation", "cursor", "display", "fill", "fill-opacity", "fill-rule", "filter", "mask", "opacity", "pointer-events", "shape-rendering", "stroke", "stroke-dasharray", "stroke-dashoffset", "stroke-linecap", "stroke-linejoin", "stroke-miterlimit", "stroke-opacity", "stroke-width", "transform", "vector-effect", "visibility"]);

const factory = (name, svgAttributes) => {
  const descriptors = { ...sharedSVGAttributes, ...attrs2props(svgAttributes) };

  return init => Object.assign(
    Object.defineProperties(
      document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", name),
      descriptors
    ),
    init
  )
}



const container = document.body
let svgContainer = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svgContainer.style.width = "100vw"
svgContainer.style.height = "100vw"
svgContainer.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 500 750");
container.appendChild(svgContainer);

// create two functions that return the respective svg element ...
const makeCircle = factory("circle", ["cx", "cy", "r"]);
const makeRect = factory("rect", ["x", "y", "width", "height", "rx", "ry"]);

let a = makeCircle({
  cx: 50,
  cy: 300,
  r: 20,
  fill: '#493fea',
  stroke: 'green'
});

let b = makeRect({
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: "blue"
})

svgContainer.appendChild(a);
svgContainer.appendChild(b);

// ... but they also have properties to change the values.
a.r = 100;
a.fill = "red";

b.width = 20;
b.stroke = "magenta";
b.strokeWidth = 5;
```

This is a very basic example, there's probably a lot to improve upon this.

The code currently doesn't take into account that some properties should return numbers, every property is a string!

Comment: Already have lots of ideas by reading this, thanks for your input! Can you explain more why " the property in your created object and the attribute on the <circle /> have no connection to each other after they were once initially set."?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are doing those circles for fun. Here is a modern funny way:

Run the SO snippet; click the viewBox

```js
customElements.define("svg-measles", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.style.display = "inline-block";
    this.style.width   = "100vw";
    this.style.height  = "100vh";
    this.colors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet'];
    this.innerHTML = `<svg style="width:100%;height:100%" viewBox="${this.getAttribute("viewbox")}"/>`;
    let svg = this.querySelector("svg");
    this.makeCircle("50%", "50%", 10, '#493fea', 'green');
    this.onclick = (evt) => {
      let svg = this.querySelector("svg");
      let pt  = svg.createSVGPoint();
      pt.x = evt.clientX;
      pt.y = evt.clientY;
      let {x,y} = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
      this.makeCircle(x, y, 10, 'green', 'yellow');
    }
  }
  makeCircle(cx, cy, r, fill, stroke, id) {
    this.colors.unshift(fill = this.colors.pop());
    this.querySelector("svg")
        .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", 
                            `<circle cx="${cx}" cy="${cy}" r="${r}" fill="${fill}" stroke="${stroke}"/>`);
  }
});
```

```html
<svg-measles viewBox="0 0 300 200"></svg-meales>
```

Comment: This post made me feel like trying to understand a joke that I wasn't in on.

Comment: Your first words were: _**I am creating circles for fun**_. So I am showing the much more versatile way.